# Is my GPU temperatures high? How can I lower it?

Tags: technical-issues, hardware

I've recently bought a Gigabyte R9 280x 3GB GDDR5 graphics card, and honestly, I'm pretty happy with it. But one thing I'm concerned is with it's temperature.

After one hour or so playing, its temperature goes to 70-72C.

I've only tested it with two games

```
Resident Evil HD remaster
Skyrim (with mods)
```

Both with max filters @ 1080p.

I guess that Skyrim is a heavier game than RE, or am I wrong? And I've got the same temperature. Is it too high? What is its risk temperature?

How can I lower its temperature without underclocking or undervolting?

Comment: what is your airflow and dust situation like? sometimes just blasting the innards of your computer with a can of compressed air is all you need to do.

Comment: Many desktop GPU's will operate at an average around 70 C. I wouldn't think 72 after an hour of heavy use is really a worry.

Comment: From my experience, the temperature rises dangerously when the fans and heat sink begin to get dusty and clogged. 70-72 seem like an acceptable range. If your GPU/CPU start to think they're too hot, they'll underclock themselves and you'll notice a MAJOR low framerate; try not getting to that point by keeping your fans clean and in proper working order!

Comment: It's a brand new computer. The case has 2 or 3 fans if i'm not mistaken: one at the front, one at the back and one at the top.

I'll see if i can get a couple more (one exhaust and one intake) just in case

Comment: You shouldn't worry, that's plenty of airflow. If you can control the top fan speed and it ain't at its fastest, that's mostly the one that will make a difference. Hot air goes up, if you can cool the air inside by making sure the hot one is going out, your GPU will have more cool air... doubt that will lower your temps as they aren't high to star with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Temperatures in the 70's aren't really high for a GPU under heavy use. Anything under 80 is very unlikely to damage the chip, and most can go into the 90s.

Answer (score 0):

Although temperatures in the 70's for a GPU are indeed normal, to know if the card is working good you require do to more research. It depends on tendencies rather than the value itself.

I read in your post "After one hour or so playing..."

Does this mean that the card starts at a lower temperature and then gradually raises? Because if that's the case then there's something wrong with your cooling. It's not necessary a matter of good airflow, you can have that, and still have a card behaving weird.

I had a card which turned out to be busted, always hanging at around 70C, It gave me issues with some games. I RMA'd it, had the same model and the card now hangs at around 60C

So, if the cards starts at 70C(on load), and maintains itself and 70C(while on load). You're fine, if there's a gradual increase something is not quite right. The card, the airflow, or the environment. Then again, if it stays at 70C-72C and it no longer increases after that, it's not really something to worry at. As long as your games work fine.

Just in case I'd recommend trying it with high resource consuming games that the card claims to support. I knew there was something wrong with my card when Bioshock Infinite and BF3 BSOD while the card spec said that those games were supported.

Comment: Well, as i said, i don't know if my case has two or three fans. I'll check it tonight. And i do live in a quite hot place. The card usually hangs on 60-65 and some minutes after (1 hour of gaming), it goes to 70-72. I'll see if i can play more than one hour to see my gpu temperature. Which games do you recommend to "stress test" it?

Comment: Tropical area? I do too, quite an issue when you look out about temperatures and people from the north post about 50C temps.
Back at your question, an increase of about 5C is still within parameters. So you shouldn't have to worry. the games could be BF3, Bioshock Infinite, Far Cry 3, FC3 Blood Dragon, Metro 2033, Metro: Last Light. But it depends mostly on what your card claims to support.

Comment: Tropical area...and it's summer time around here. I'll check those games when i can.